# Using an optocoupler to put an AC signal on a DC bias

Tags: opto-isolator

Expanding from this question [Can an opto-isolated input be analog?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/139605/can-an-opto-isolated-input-be-analog/139609#139609):

Can you use an optocoupler to take an AC signal and attach it to a DC bias? More specifically, can you take something like a 1V sine wave and put it on top of a 300VDC bias. As a starting point, the frequency range will be from 10Hz to 10kHz.

---

Edit:

I am attempting to replace the isolation transformer in the following circuit. Note, the load attached is a possible example but is able to change based upon the application.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIOcqC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: How about a picture of what you have in mind.  (You want the output to be 1 V ac on top of 300 V dc?)  Maybe a little audio transformer would be easier?  (I don't know if they can handle 300V.)

Comment: Optocouplers can surely be used for this purpose. See Marston's *Optoelectronics Circuits Manual*, [p. 127](https://books.google.com/books?id=W6m7NC0nvE8C&pg=PA127) for how to pass analog audio (which is close enough to the frequency range you want) via an optocoupler. You just have to add the DC bias. Sorry I don't have the time to make your requested circuit. Drawing takes time... I should caution you that opto-coupled audio doesn't sound great. You probably need to think a bit (an perhaps specify) how much distortion you can live with, etc.

Comment: @ Respawned Fluff: If I am thinking about this correctly, I would need to return the negative output of the opto to my DC bias and the positive to something like 5V above the DC bias. If I use an isolated DCDC converter, can I attach the output's negative to 300VDC?